# C# Extracting values from file

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a file of the format as below.

The file represents a point file generated by robot with the attributes of each points (Point1 and Point2) such as **label(slabel)**, **xcordinate(rX)**, **ycordinate(rY)** etc. listed inside the curly braces **{ }**. The file is created by the native robot application and the method they used is unknown.

```
nNumberOfJoints=6
nNumberOfPoints=2
Point1 {
    nNumber=0
    sLabel="FirstPost"
    sDescription="Desc one"
    nUndefined=0
    rX=-48.515
    rY=600.175
    rZ=821.792
    rU=92.684
    rV=-89.851
    rW=177.32
    rR=0
    rS=0
    rT=0
    nLocal=0
    nHand=1
    nElbow=1
    nWrist=1
    nJ1Flag=0
    nJ2Flag=0
    nJ4Flag=0
    nJ6Flag=0
    rJ1Angle=0
    rJ4Angle=0
    bSimVisible=False
}
Point2 {
    nNumber=1
    sLabel="SecondPost"
    sDescription="Desc two"
    nUndefined=0
    rX=-48.514
    rY=610.175
    rZ=611.808
    rU=92.662
    rV=-89.851
    rW=177.342
    rR=0
    rS=0
    rT=0
    nLocal=0
    nHand=1
    nElbow=1
    nWrist=1
    nJ1Flag=0
    nJ2Flag=0
    nJ4Flag=0
    nJ6Flag=0
    rJ1Angle=0
    rJ4Angle=0
    bSimVisible=False
}
```

The file is of **.pts** extension but it can be read as any normal text file. I need to read the file and get the parameters for Point1 and Point2.

Am hoping for something like ***Point1.slabel*** or ***Point2.nNumber*** so that it can be passed to other functions.

Am guessing a dictionary method will be good but am not sure how to execute it.

Can someone suggest the ideal way to approach this or give any insights?

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to write a parser for the format. Shouldn't be very hard: if a line ends with `{`, it starts a new block. If it contains a `=`, you can split it by it and read in the key and value into a dictionary.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239398/Creating-a-Custom-De-Serializer

Comment: presumably the properties of a point may vary, based on the number of joints?

Comment: @Jodrell No, Joints will be fixed, the count of points may vary but the properties remains same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a standalone program that parses your data (assumed to be in `example.txt`) into a nested dictionary (that maps block names to key-value pairs):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace so67801246
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var variables = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
            var currentBlock = "GLOBAL";
            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("example.txt"))
            {
                if (line.EndsWith("{"))
                {
                    currentBlock = line.Trim(' ', '{');
                    continue;
                }
                if (line.Contains("="))
                {
                    var bits = line.Trim().Split('=', 2);
                    Dictionary<string, string> coll;
                    if (!variables.TryGetValue(currentBlock, out coll))
                    {
                        coll = variables[currentBlock] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    }
                    coll[bits[0]] = bits[1];
                }
            }
            foreach (var blockToVars in variables)
            {
                var block = blockToVars.Key;
                foreach (var pair in blockToVars.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} = {2}", block, pair.Key, pair.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
GLOBAL.nNumberOfJoints = 6
GLOBAL.nNumberOfPoints = 2
Point1.nNumber = 0
Point1.sLabel = "FirstPost"
Point1.sDescription = "Desc one"
Point1.nUndefined = 0
Point1.rX = -48.515
# ... snip ...
Point2.nNumber = 1
Point2.sLabel = "SecondPost"
Point2.sDescription = "Desc two"
Point2.nUndefined = 0
Point2.rX = -48.514
Point2.rY = 610.175
# ... snip ...
```

It does not deal with decoding numbers or unquoting quoted strings, but that's easy enough.